# Фильтрация спектра сигнала с помощью фильтра Баттерворта

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться с фильтрацией спектра сигнала, импортируемого из csv файла, с помощью фильтра низких частот Баттерворта.

При применении ФНЧ Баттерворта  к спектру получаю такую ошибку:

> output = filtfilt(b, a, spectrum)
> File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\scipy\signal\signaltools.py", line 3893, in filtfilt
> edge, ext = _validate_pad(padtype, padlen, x, axis,
> File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\scipy\signal\signaltools.py", line 3943, in _validate_pad
> raise ValueError("The length of the input vector x must be greater "
> ValueError: The length of the input vector x must be greater than padlen, which is 1503.

Сам код:

```
import pandas as pd     #import csv file
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
from numpy.fft import rfft, rfftfreq
from scipy.signal import butter, sosfilt, sosfreqz, filtfilt
from math import sin, pi
from pylab import *
from scipy import *
import os


df = pd.read_csv('1.csv', sep=",",  usecols= [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]) #прочтение файла csv
print(df.loc[1]) # вывод значений


#Преобразование Фурье
Fs = 5000
N = 10
spectrum = rfft(df.loc[1]) # прямое одномерное ДПФ
t = np.arange(1000)/Fs
lowcut = 500
highcut = 2000

plt.plot(np.arange(N)/float(Fs), df.loc[1]) # по оси времени секунды!
plt.xlabel(u'Время, c') # это всё запускалось в Python 2.7, поэтому юникодовские строки
plt.ylabel(u'Напряжение, мВ')
plt.title(u'Сигнал из файла')
plt.grid(True) #активация сетки
plt.show()     #показ графика

# rfftfreq возвращает частоты для выходных массивов функций fft
plt.plot(rfftfreq(N, 1./Fs), np.abs(spectrum)/N) # построение спектра
plt.xlabel(u'Частота, Гц')
plt.ylabel(u'Напряжение, мВ')
plt.title(u'Спектр')
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()



#Сглаживание сигнала и фильтрация

fc = 1000  # Cut-off frequency of the filter
w = fc/(Fs/2) # Normalize the frequency
b, a = butter(30, w, 'low')
output = filtfilt(b, a, spectrum)
plt.plot(t, output, label='filtered')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
b, a = butter(30, w, 'low')
output = filtfilt(b, a, spectrum)
```

> ValueError: The length of the input vector x must be greater than
> padlen, which is 1503.

Смотрим документацию на [filtfilt](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.filtfilt.html):

```
padlen: ... The default value is 3 * max(len(a), len(b)).
```

Т.е. у вас `max(len(a), len(b)) = 1503/3 = 501` и это больше, чем размер вашего `spectrum`.
Что делать? Как-то уменьшить `a` и `b`. Смотрим документацию на [butter](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.butter.html):

```
scipy.signal.butter(N, Wn, btype='low', analog=False, output='ba', fs=None)
N: int, The order of the filter.
```

При этом в примерах которые я видел везде ну `3`, ну `4` пишут в качестве `N`, а чтобы `30` - такого не видел.

В общем, попробуйте уменьшить `N` до `3`, например. Хотя может я не прав и дело в `Wn`. Сложно размышлять, не имея возможность пощупать данные самому.